# Unique validation not working in feathers/mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, feathersjs

email: {
type: String,
unique: true,
lowercase: true.valueOf,
required: true
},

above is my code block for mongoose model.
the unique property is not working , I can create multiple users for the same email id

Comment: I am using nodemon, that restarts the server each time a change is made.

Comment: So, press `ctrl + c`  in the node terminal and start nodemon again.

Comment: also share your mongoose config , `useCreateIndex` must be true`